# Modifying previous line c++

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to make the Conway's game of life in c++ for a school project. The problem is I don't know how to make the board more "dynamic". How can I return several lines to change the output I made before? Right now I have to print various boards which isn't exactly aesthetic.

Looking this up on previous questions I could only find "/r" which helps if the board is only one line, but in my case it isn't.

Edit: Added code sample (if it helps).

```
for (int temp = 0; temp < iterations; temp++){
  for(long long i = 0; i < height; ++i){
    for(long long j = 0; j < width; ++j){
      if (CurrentGen[i][j]){
        cout << "■" << " ";
      }
      else{
        cout << "." << " ";
      }
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
  cout << "---------------------------------------" << endl;
  CurrentGen = NextGen(CurrentGen, height, width);
  sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Print board. Calculate new board. Clear screen. Print board. Etc etc. Classic game loop.

Comment: @Jesper That kind of begs the question "how do I clear the screen?"

Comment: @NeilButterworth A hammer works. But it only works once.  C++ provides an output stream. Once something is in the stream, it's up to the recipient to decide whether or not you can go backwards. Many don't. Most don't make it easy. The solution is to use a terminal library like [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) to do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @NeilButterworth If using a text console I'd let `ncurses` deal with the details of that. If using graphics, your graphics library will have a function for that - as you well know :)

Comment: @Jesper Yes, I know that - my point was that the OP probably doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, although I do not see how code is necessary for the question in this case. Regardless I will keep that in mind and add code in the future even if I don't see the need for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will end up being more than complicated solution for the system dependent code.

However the easy and quick solution is for visually having the same line being updated is to create many empty lines for every loop iteration.

```
for (int n = 0; n < 50; n++)
    {
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
```

As I said earlier this is the best C++ could do when there is no system information available, using only the standard commands.

There are other ways to do it such as:

1. `system` call to clear the terminal

   - [but this method not safe](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/j3wTURfi/)
2. The standard way to print end lines
3. Using the ncurses library `#include <curses.h>`

   - Advantage: it is a cross-platform
   - Disadvantage: cannot be mixed with standard I/O

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick answer, suppose I will use your solution and try learning curser libraries for the future.

Comment: @HectorOfTheRose I have fixed a typo: You want curses (possibly ncurses), not curser.

Comment: The cursor library typo has reappeared.